# Expression for 'You just said words to appease me'

Tags: expressions

I remember an expression that's something like 'you're just giving me words.'  The idea is that someone says, 'yeah, i'll do abc.'  And you respond... 'Okay, let me know when it's done, so I can check.'  And they respond.  'What?  You don't believe I'll do it?'  And i want to respond, 'I just want to make sure you're not 'expression goes here.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Paying lip service**

From dictionary.com [Lip service](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lip-service):

> insincere expression of friendship, admiration, support, etc.; service by words only:
>
> He paid only lip service to the dictator.

In your example, the response would be "I just want to be sure you're not simply paying me lip service". That is, you want to make sure that the statements of agreement are backed up with suitable actions.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer "lip service" is fine, but there are very many options. You can refer to the speech or speech act: "You're not just saying that", "you're not just telling me that", "you're just not promising me that"...
Or use various slang phrases: "You're not just (bull)shitting me"...
There are many more possibilities.